# Pandas divide fill with multiple values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, na

I have two pandas series objects with slightly different indexes. I want to divide one series by another. The default method gives me NAs when one of the two series is missing an indexed element. There is an option to fill missing values, but it can only be set to one value. I want to fill a value based on which series is missing the value.

For example

```
series1
0 10
1 20
2 30
3 40


series2
1 2
2 3
3 4
4 5

expected result: series1.divide(series2)
0 inf
1 10
2 10
3 10
4 0

actual result: series1.divide(series2)
0 NaN
1 10
2 10
3 10
4 NaN
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to expand `series1.index` to include `series2.index`, filling missing values with 0. Then you could use the `div` method, which fills in missing values with NaN by default:

```
series1 = pd.Series([10,20,30,40], index=[0,1,2,3])
series2 = pd.Series([2,3,4,5], index=[1,2,3,4])
series1 = series1.reindex(series1.index.union(series2.index), fill_value=0)
print(series1.div(series2))
# 0        nan
# 1   10.00000
# 2   10.00000
# 3   10.00000
# 4    0.00000
# dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried something similar series1.divide(series2.reindex_like(series1+series2).fillna(0)) but that gave a slightly different result.